# Read a single cell from Excel to a string using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I need to read a single cell from an xsl excel file to a string withing the web application i am building. I was previously pulling cell ranges from the file to a table using the following code:

```
string PullFromExcell(string CellNo)
    {
        string cell;
        string properties = String.Format(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.xls; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0;'");

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(properties))
        {
            string worksheet = "Sheet";
            conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheet + "$" + CellNo + "]", properties))
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cell = dt.ToString(); 
                da.Fill(dt);
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                grdComponent.DataSource = dt;
                grdComponent.DataBind();
            }
        }

       return cell;
    }
```

How would i send that to a string? The code that i would use when pulling from a database is similar to this:

```
Sqlstring = "Select data from variable where name = 'fred' and ssn = 1234";
var cmd0 = new SqlCommand(Sqlstring, Class_Connection.cnn);
string Data = cmd0.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

i'm just not sure if any of that is compatible.

Comment: Can you explain, "send that to a string"? PullFromExcell function does return a string.

Comment: OleDbDataAdapter is intended to pull the data from a single cell. I need to take the contents of that cell and and insert it into the string variable "cell" so that i can return that variable to the main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filling DataTable, you can search the row like this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    if (dr["name"] == "fred" && dr["ssn"] == "1234")
    {
        cell = dr["data"].ToString();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm currently working with this and playing with the code. my understanding of how the data us pulled, there will be no column name, as the table that the initial pull from is just a single cell from a spreadsheet and not a database table.
since there is no column name to identify, could i just use "cell = dr.Tostring()"?

Comment: It will take the first row as columns. So, you can get the cell value for certain column for each row.

Comment: I pulled 2 consecutive cells from one column and the DT named the column F1 with the second cell in the range listed as the only row of data. this allowed me to use the following code in place of the above code. I removed the if statement because i didn't need to search, just pull the single column of data.

`foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
 {
      cell = dr["F1"].ToString();
  }`