# Attempting to migrate data from a spreadsheet to a Database using C# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I receive that I need to import into a table in our database. I have previously asked about pulling a single cell of data from a spreadsheet ([Read a single cell from Excel to a string using C# and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172574/read-a-single-cell-from-excel-to-a-string-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net)) and I am attempting to build off of this in order to move an entire spreadsheet into the database.

The format of the information is Column 1 = Name, Column 2 = Wage, Column 3 = Department

The existing code is as follows:

```
#region Initialize Connection
var Class_Connection = new SQL_Connection();
var sql = new SQL_Statements();
Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
#endregion

string properties = String.Format(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = \\Hera\Public\LumberPrices\lbr_ems.xls; Extended Properties = 'Excel 8.0; HDR = NO;'");
string Price = "";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(properties))
{
    string sqlpull = "SELECT * FROM [" + worksheet + "$" + Cell1 + ":" + Cell2 + "]";
    conn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //string columns = String.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray());

    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlpull, properties))
    {
        string temp2 = "";

        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            temp2 = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Price = dr[temp2].ToString();
        }
    }
}

int Freight = GetFreight(LumbDesc);
int price1 = Convert.ToInt32(Price);
int addon = Convert.ToInt32(AddTo);
int Total = price1 + addon + Freight;

//TODO: insert into TLumberprice
string sqlStatement = "insert table([LumberCode], [Price], [PriceDate], [UserName], [Factor], [Op])" +
                      "values ('" + LumbDesc + "', '" + Total + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "', '" + LoginSession.userName.Remove(LoginSession.userName.Length - 1) + "', '" + Factor + "', '" + OP + "')";

#region Insert Lumber Prices
Class_Connection.cnn.Open();

SqlCommand InsertLumberPrices = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, Class_Connection.cnn);
InsertLumberPrices.ExecuteNonQuery();

Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
#endregion
```

This works as intended. but I have questions.

Can I read the `DataTable(dt)` straight into the database, or do I have to use something like the following?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    SName = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString();
    SWage = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName.ToString();
    SDept = dt.Columns[2].ColumnName.ToString();
}

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    Name = dr[SName].tostring();
    Wage = dr[SWage].tostring();
    Dept = dr[SDept].tostring();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of importing the data from a data table into the SQL Table.
You need to use SqlBulkCopy

`var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);`

You can even map which data table column goes to which SQL Table column as well.

Here is an example.

```
using(var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Column 1", "Name"));
    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Column 2", "Wage"));
    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Column 3", "Department"));
    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table" // table name in SQL

    conn.Open();
    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Where conn is your SqlConnection.

If you don't want to use the data table, you could go directly to the BulkImport.

Just change the OleDbDataAdapter to OleDbCommand and put the value in an IDataReader variable, which then you can use in the code above instead of dt.

With the last part, I only did it in the past between 2 SQL servers that did not have a link to each other. I'm not sure 100% sure if it will work with OleDb.

Comment: I like that your solution is clean and straightforward and quite easy to understand. My follow-up question is "does this allow for outside information?" specifically, I need to enter a date and an overtime rate based on the wage field.

I will freely admit that I am not a programmer and looking up the technical data makes my eyes cross.

Comment: wait... I could just insert the data I need into the DataTable and then use SqlBulkCopy to move the whole thing into the database table. right?

Comment: You can enter the data in the DataTable before using SqlBulkCopy, but you will either need to create a DataTable before filling it with Excel Data or add additional empty columns in Excel which you will load in the DataTable. If you don't do that, you won't have the columns in the DataTable to add the additional info.
Alternatively, you could use SqlBulkCopy and then do an update to the SQL Database.

Comment: So, as far as this answer thread goes, what I'm looking at for keeping the code as automated as possible is to do a BulkCopy, then go back and "Insert a date into the table where the date is currently null", correct?

Comment: Also, the second parameters ("Column 1", "Name") i would need to change that to what i actually in the Excel sheet and table, correct? For example ("Employee Name", "EmpName")

Comment: After you populate the DataTable with the data from the Excel file you can add some extra columns to your DataTable. For example if its a DateTime filed `dt.Columns.Add("Date").DataType = Type.GetType("System.DateTime");` or for Integer `dt.Columns.Add("dattim").DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");` Once you added them, then you can populate them with the data you require before finally adding them to your Database.
Alternatively, you could just import them as is and do an SQL Update afterward. I think the first option is better.

Comment: To your second question, yes the first part is the column name of the DataTable and the second part is the column name of the SQL Table.

Comment: thank you so much. Before I saw your most recent comments, I went ahead and set it to fill the table then go back and add the date to the records afterwards. everything is working as desired.